# Jquery Ajax call return Parsererror?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have written Jquery Ajax call but i got Parsererror.. in following js code i have checked which select element is changed in `dynamic_slct`. and i have checked generic or Company and then call `GnrtTemp()` with pass selected Element value.. if I select generic my follwing Code(function GnrtTemp and ajax call) is working.. if i select company i got Error parsererror.. my doubt is same ajax call working Generic and is not working as company.. what is the problem? How to fix that problem i have attached my js code and also PHP code .. If i did any mistake pls correct me.. suggest to solution.?

JS

```
$('#dynmic_slct').on("change", "#master ,select[name='company'], select[name='generic']", function(element){
    if(element.target.name == 'generic' || element.target.name == 'company')          {

            GnrtTemp(element.target.value);
}
});
function GnrtTemp(id){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "ajaxRequest.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {fn: "getTemp", id: id},
        success: function(reqResult){},
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
          alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

ajaxRequest.php

```
<?php

  $finalRes = array();
  if($_POST['fn'] == 'getTemp'){

        $template_src = getTemp($_POST['id']);

        $finalRes['result'] = $template_src;
        echo json_encode($finalRes);    
    }

    function getTemp($id){

       $db = new DB();

       $Query = "SELECT template_src
        FROM master
        WHERE refid =$id";

       $qryRes = $db->query($Query);

      return $qryRes;

   }
```

?>

Comment: Looks like  server error. Also $_POST['evnt_id'] should have no value in it and be undefined..

Comment: where is the closing of your `$('#dynmic_slct').on("change")`? all I can see is closing in your `if statement`. I think it is missing `});`

Comment: can you add your `select` tag?

Comment: can  you check your ajaxRequest.php full path.i think it's ajax request not going on this file

Comment: i have added dynamically in select tag `success: function(reqResult){
       
      var append_string = '<div class="col-lg-8">'+ 
         '<select class="chosen" name="generic" style="width:200px;">';
        append_string += '<option>--select--<option>'; 
          $.each(reqResult.result, function(ind, va){
          append_string += '<option value='+va.event_id+'>'+va.event_name+'</option>';
         }); 
         
       append_string += '</select>'+
          '</div>';
        
        $('#dynmic_slct').html(append_string);
        jQuery(".chosen").chosen();
      }` @pryxen

Comment: did you wrap your `$('#dynmic_slct').on("change")` in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: yes i have written inside the `$(document).ready()` @pryxen

Comment: I tested your code, I think your problem is in your Ajax Request

Comment: how to fix? because generic request return correct result but company request return parsererror.. i dont understant this bug ? @pryxen

Comment: your `select[name='company']` is it inside the `#dynmic_slct`? because all I can see is you append your `select[name='generic']` and there is no `select[name='company']`

Comment: yes `select[name='company']` inside the `#dynmic_slct`@pryxen

Comment: Can you remove the `dataType: "JSON",` and try your code again

Comment: after romve the dataType, again throw the parsererror!@pryxen

Comment: i have removed dataType and change php code as follow `echo $template_src = "sample Text";exit;` but i got same error `parsererror`@pryxen

Comment: check this post @BalakumarB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061310/jquery-returning-parsererror-for-ajax-request