# How to successfully pass a Json to render and manipulate it in Django?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django, python-3.x

I am trying to return a Json response from a POST request but I am encountering various errors in the path.

First, I have the following view

```
class ChartData8(APIView):
    def tickets_per_day_results(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            template_name = 'personal_website/tickets_per_day_results.html'
            year = request.POST.get('select_year', None)
            week = request.POST.get('select_week', None)
            ....do stuff...
            data = {"label_number_days": label_number_days,
                    "days_of_data": count_of_days}
        return render(request,template_name,JsonResponse(data))
```

that calls the template **tickets_per_day_results.html** which contains an Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: endpoint,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {"X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken")},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        label_number_days = data.label_number_days
        days_of_data = data.days_of_data
        setChart()

    },
    error: function(jqXHR,error_data, errorThrown){
        console.log("error on data")
        console.log(error_data)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR))
        console.log("AJAX error: " + error_data + ' : ' + errorThrown)
    }
```

but this combination throws me `context must be a dict rather than JsonResponse` error.

I tried various alternatives:

**Alternative 1:** Instead of `JsonResponse` I used `Response` like the following:

```
class ChartData8(APIView):
    def tickets_per_day_results(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            template_name = 'personal_website/tickets_per_day_results.html'
            year = request.POST.get('select_year', None)
            week = request.POST.get('select_week', None)
            ....do stuff...
            data = {"label_number_days": label_number_days,
                    "days_of_data": count_of_days}
        return render(request,template_name,Response(data))
```

but this threw out the error `context must be a dict rather than Response`.

**Alternative 2:** Instead of `JsonResponse` and `Response` I tried to convert the object to a dict  like the following:

```
class ChartData8(APIView):
    def tickets_per_day_results(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            template_name = 'personal_website/tickets_per_day_results.html'
            year = request.POST.get('select_year', None)
            week = request.POST.get('select_week', None)
            ....do stuff...
            data = {"label_number_days": label_number_days,
                    "days_of_data": count_of_days}
        return render(request,template_name, dict(Response(data)))
```

but this threw out the error `The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over`.

**Alternative 3:** Instead of 1 and 2 I tried to pass data without `JsonResponse` nor `Response`:

```
class ChartData8(APIView):
    def tickets_per_day_results(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            template_name = 'personal_website/tickets_per_day_results.html'
            year = request.POST.get('select_year', None)
            week = request.POST.get('select_week', None)
            ....do stuff...
            data = {"label_number_days": label_number_days,
                    "days_of_data": count_of_days}
        return render(request,template_name, data)
```

but this threw out the error `parsererror` from the ajax request because this means you simply return a string or another value, it is not really `Json`, so the parser fails when parsing it. You can avoid this error by removing `dataType:'json'` from the Ajax request (solution from [parsererror Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061310/jquery-returning-parsererror-for-ajax-request)) but this will not allow me to manipulate my datasets from my template **tickets_per_day_results**, that is,

remove `dataType:json`

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: endpoint,
    headers: {"X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken")},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        label_number_days = data.label_number_days
        days_of_data = data.days_of_data
        setChart()

    },
    error: function(jqXHR,error_data, errorThrown){
        console.log("error on data")
        console.log(error_data)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR))
        console.log("AJAX error: " + error_data + ' : ' + errorThrown)
    }
```

then I cannot manipulate my datasets that are found below the Ajax request:

```
data: {
        labels: label_number_days,
        datasets :
            [{
                label: 'User_001',
                data [days_of_data[0],days_of_data[1],days_of_data[2],days_of_data[3],days_of_data[4],days_of_data[5],days_of_data[6]],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                borderColor: '#777',
                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            },
```

because you found `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

This has been a tedious path and I am running out of ideas (and patience). If anyone can suggest me any other alternative then that will give me some health relief.

**Update**
**Tickets per day results html file**

```
{% extends "personal_website/header.html"%}

<script>
{% block jquery %}

var endpoint = '/tickets_per_day_results/' //This works with the chart_data view.

var days_of_data = []
var label_number_days = []

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: endpoint,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {"X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken")},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        label_number_days = data.label_number_days
        days_of_data = data.days_of_data
        setChart()

    },
    error: function(jqXHR,error_data, errorThrown){
        console.log("error on data")
        console.log(error_data)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR))
        console.log("AJAX error: " + error_data + ' : ' + errorThrown)
    }
})
function setChart()
{var ctx_tickets_per_day       = document.getElementById("tickets_per_day")

var tickets_per_day = new Chart(ctx_tickets_per_day, {
    showTooltips: false,
    type:'bar',
    data: {
        labels: label_number_days,
        datasets :
            [{
                label: 'Oscar Gil',
                data: [days_of_data[0],days_of_data[1],days_of_data[2],days_of_data[3],days_of_data[4],days_of_data[5],days_of_data[6]],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                borderColor: '#777',
                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            },
            {
                label: 'Oscar Rodriguez',
                data: [days_of_data[7],days_of_data[8],days_of_data[9],days_of_data[10],days_of_data[11],days_of_data[12],days_of_data[13]],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                borderColor: '#777',
                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            },

            {
                label: 'Animesh Rathore',
                data: [days_of_data[14],days_of_data[15],days_of_data[16],days_of_data[17],days_of_data[18],days_of_data[19],days_of_data[20]],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
                borderColor: '#777',
                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            },

            {
                label: 'Bhaskar Sharma',
                data: [days_of_data[21],days_of_data[22],days_of_data[23],days_of_data[24],days_of_data[25],days_of_data[26],days_of_data[27]],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
                borderColor: '#777',
                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            },

            {
                label: 'Victor Catacora',
                data: [days_of_data[28],days_of_data[29],days_of_data[30],days_of_data[31],days_of_data[32],days_of_data[33],days_of_data[34]],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
                borderColor: '#777',
                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            },

            {
                label: 'Jimmy Gonzalez',
                data: [days_of_data[35],days_of_data[36],days_of_data[37],days_of_data[38],days_of_data[39],days_of_data[40],days_of_data[41]],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(236, 115, 9, 1)',
                borderColor: '#777',
                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            },

            {
                label: 'Piyush Gupta',
                data: [days_of_data[42],days_of_data[43],days_of_data[44],days_of_data[45],days_of_data[46],days_of_data[47],days_of_data[48]],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(185, 29, 12, 0.6)',
                borderColor: '#777',
                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            },

            {
                label: 'Carlos Prieto',
                data: [days_of_data[49],days_of_data[50],days_of_data[51],days_of_data[52],days_of_data[53],days_of_data[54],days_of_data[55]],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(105, 129, 64, 0.6)',
                borderColor: '#777',
                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            },

            {
                label: 'Daniel Estrada',
                data: [days_of_data[56],days_of_data[57],days_of_data[58],days_of_data[59],days_of_data[60],days_of_data[61],days_of_data[62]],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(15,  199, 84, 0.6)',
                borderColor: '#777',
                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            },

            ]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
          },

          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Tickets by engineer per day',
            fontSize: 30
            },
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            display: true,
            labels: {
                fontColor: '#000'
                }
            },
            layout: {
                padding: {
                    left: 50,
                    right: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    top: 0
                    }
            },
            tooltips: {
              enabled: true
            },

          hover : {
            animationDuration: 0
          },

          animation: {
            duration: 0.8,
            onComplete: function(){
                var chartInstance = this.chart,
                ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#777';
                ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize,
                           Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                var isHidden = dataset._meta[0].hidden; //'hidden' property of dataset
                if (!isHidden) { //if dataset is not hidden
                    var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                    meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                        var data = dataset.data[index];
                        ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);});
                    }});
            }
          }
        }
    })
}

{% endblock %}
```

```
    {% block content %}

<div class ='row'>

    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="col-sm-12" url-endpoint='{% url "tickets_per_day_results" %}'>
        <div>
            <canvas id="tickets_per_day" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
 {% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're using the wrong method for returning data in JSON format. 
In the code :

```
render(request,template_name,JsonResponse(data))
```

In the documentation of Django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/). The render shortcut is used to render an Html Template with dictionary data to update the page.

According to the django code I guess you use Django rest Framework. 
In order to send JSON data you should use the example here [DRF example response](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) in order to send JSON data to the page.

Comment: But how can you render the data with the template?

Comment: For the rendering the data in the template you have to remove the JsonResponse(data), and put only data.

Comment: The problem is that if I put only `data` then I will encounter the `parsererror` problem and to avoid this I have to erase `dataType: 'json` and doing this will lead to the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: could you please share your template 'personal_website/tickets_per_day_results.html' just to have a look please.

Comment: There are some 100 lines of code, but I will upload it now.

Comment: Upload successful!

Comment: Ok I see more clearly, you're using the method post through an ajax call. and you should not use render as a return of the request. Using directly "return JsonResponse(data)"  on the post method you have done