# Respose data shows on dev tools but not on AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb, mongoose

My get ajax isn't getting the response:

```
$.get(
    '/api/entity',
    function(item){
        console.log(item); //<-- doesn't show anything at all
    }
);
```

However, when I go to `/api/entity` on the browser or check the dev tools, I see the response I'm expecting from the request. Furthermore, when I log XMLHttpRequests, I get `XHR finished loading: GET`.

I changed the method of how I get data from mongodb. Instead of sending an array of all the data via callback, I'm now piping the stream directly to `res`.

Previous method:

```
db.entity.find({},function(err,data){
    res.end(data);
});
```

Current method:

```
db.entity.find({}).cursor({transform:JSON.stringify}).pipe(res);
```

I need to know how to get the response on ajax.

Comment: Is the browser get to the function? I mean if you put on this line a break point..

Comment: Hi, Mosh. It doesn't seem to get to the function at all. That's mainly my question. I know there is a response, but the function isn't getting called.

Comment: You can try to implement it with `done`. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8840315/863110) for more info. Also, have you tried to catch an error? Read [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jqxhr-object) how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, Mosh. I implemented `done`, `fail`, and `always`. `done` didn't run but `fail` and `always` did. Both have the status of 200 and statusText of 'parseerror'. They also both have all the data I needed in the responseText.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11507572/863110) could help you with it.