# then() in JS Promise is never executed

Tags: javascript, promise

There is a funcion returning a promise:

```
req.postP = function () {

    var $promise = $.ajax({
        url: self._url(url),
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: headers,
        contentType: self.JSON_CONTENT_TYPE,
        dataType: "json"
    });

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        return $promise.then(resolve, reject);
    } );

}
```

And another function that calls the first function:

```
req
    .postP(POST_REGISTER, userData)
    .then((data) => {
        // is never ecexuted
    }) 
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(typeof err.then === "function"); // true
    });
```

The `then()` function is never executed.

It seems that the promise is inside the catch function as `err` since `err.then` is a function.

The `req.postP()` function is called by other function as well and works in those cases.

Comment: `return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {...} );` ... do you ever `resolve` in whatever `...` is?

Comment: If the `catch` block runs, then `reject` must be getting called instead of `resolve`

Comment: or there's an error thrown in `...` - that will end in the same result as calling `reject` ... without seeing relevant code, it sure is a mystery

Comment: need to get your Promise..

Comment: @JaromandaX I added the Promise.

Comment: well, clearly your jquerey ajax never succeeds - note, no need to do that by the way ... just `return Promise.resolve($.ajax({......}))` or even just `return $.ajax({....})` ... though, I don't trust jquerey promises :p

Comment: You just need to `return $promise` because jquery ajax is already a promise

Comment: try ... `.catch(err => console.error)` - at least then you'll actually see what the error actually is ... and check the developer tools console to see if the request is succeeding

Comment: @TanDuong - or `return Promise.resolve($promise)` (as I alluded to) because jquerey promises are not that good (especially in early versions - depends on the version of jquerey)

Comment: @JaromandaX: yes, we can also do like this :)

Answer (score 0):

The casting to a standard promise, was not the problem.

The problem was the `dataType`. According to the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

Since the server does not return any data for this request on success - but jQuery expected data - the promise was always rejected.

Related:
[jQuery returning "parsererror" for ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061310/jquery-returning-parsererror-for-ajax-request/11507572#11507572)